# Is it possible to override a method inline?

Tags: ios, objective-c, overriding

I'm trying to create a UIView, and I'm curious if it's possible to override its touchesBegan in the same line I'm creating it?

Something like this:

```
UIView view = new UIView() {
    @Override
    public void touchesBegan(...) {
        ...
    }
};
```

That's how it would be done in Java, but I'm curious if something similar exists in Objective-C?

Comment: You have to subclass `UIView` for that

Comment: That's what I figured, just wanted to make sure. Want to change your comment to an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subclass `UIView` for that. Also, the syntax would be:

```
MyView *myView = [MyView new];
```